# Reactjs, control a list input

Tags: reactjs, list, input, components, ref

I need to control a list of list of input like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const testData = [
  {
    name: "list 1",
    content: [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: " this is value 1 of list 1"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: " this is value 2 of list 1"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: " this is value 3 of list 1 "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "list 2",
    content: [
      {
        id: 1,
        value: " this is value 1 of list 2"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        value: " this is value 2 of list 2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        value: " this is vainput'liste 3 of list 2"
      }
    ]
  }
];

class MyList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.list
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const newData = this.state.data;
    newData[index] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  };

  updateData = newData => {
    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  };

  add = () => {
    const newData = this.state.data;
    newData.push({
      id: newData.length + 1,
      value: "new data"
    });
    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  };

  remove = (e, index) => {
    const newData = this.state.data;
    newData.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      data: newData
    });
  };

  save = (e, index) => {
    //TODO
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.add}> Add </button>
        <button onClick={this.save}> save </button>
        <tr>input'list
          {this.state.data.map((item, index) => (
            <td>
              <input
                value={item.value}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, index)}
              />
              title
              <button onClick={e => this.remove(e, index)}> remove </button>
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </div>
    );
  }
}input'list

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: testData[0].name,
      data: testData[0].content
    };
    this.ref = React.createRef();
  }

  changeList = (e, index) => {
    this.setState({
      title: testData[index].name,
      data: testData[index].content
    });
    this.ref.current.updateData(testData[index].content);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {testData.map((item, index) => (
          <button onClick={e => this.changeList(e, index)}>
            {" "}
            {item.name}{" "}
          </button>
        ))}
        this is {this.state.title}
        <MyList ref={this.ref} list={this.state.data}>
          {" "}
        </MyList>{" "}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

I need some basic method like show list, save, add more input in list, remove ... And with my code, everything works fine. But I feel it's not clean since there's many ways to do 1 thing in React. Can someone read it and give me some feedback? There's 2 things I thought are not good, but I don't know how to improve:

1. function handleChange of component MyList: I have to calculator index of input to re-render.
2. I use A Ref to update and get Data from component MyList.

Comment: If this is **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Comment: thank you, I don't know that page :D